# How to Enable /Disable test step in soapUI using Groovy script ( inside each test cases) Based on which test step user wanted to enable or disable

Tags: groovy, soapui

How to Enable /Disable test step in soapUI using Groovy script (inside each test cases) Based on which teststep user wanted to enable or disable.
Like:

- If I have one test cases and that test cases having 10 steps. I wanted to execute only those test cases which start with Online.
- If I have one test cases and that test cases having 10 step . I wanted to execute only those test cases which start with Batch.

Please find below sample which is throwing error:
`Sat May 20 11:35:14 CEST 2017:ERROR:An error occurred [java.lang.NullPointerException], see error log for details while executing the next test cases.`

Code:

```
context.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseList().each
 {
    log.info "Test Case : ${it.name}".toUpperCase();
    it.testStepList.each 
    {
           log.info "Test Step--> : ${it.name}"

         def testStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName( "${it.name}" 
         log.info testStep.disabled
         if( testStep.disabled )
         {
            testStep.disabled = false

         }

      testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("${it.name}").setDisabled(true)
            log.info testStep.disabled
            log.info "Action Perfomed for Test Step : ${it.name}"

    }
 }
```

Comment: please add the stacktrace of your exception

Comment: Summary says disable teststep, where the description says execute only specific test cases and does not talk about test steps. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi Rao, sorry for confusion. Yes I am looking for testSteps only.

Comment: Still missing the clarity, not sure what steps to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, 
`def testStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName( "${it.name}"` is unecessary. It looks for a testStep with a special name in the testSuite containing the script that you run, which isn't there and you get a NullPointer exception. 
It can be simply replaced by 'it'

```
context.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseList().each
{
    log.info "Test Case : ${it.name}".toUpperCase();
    it.testStepList.each 
    {
         log.info "Test Step--> : ${it.name}"

         log.info it.disabled
         if( it.disabled )
         {
            it.disabled = false
         }

        it.setDisabled(true)
        log.info it.disabled
        log.info "Action Perfomed for Test Step : ${it.name}"
    }
}
```